# How to reverse-engineer/find datasheet for an IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, reverse-engineering

I have an integrated circuit in the form as a DIN chip, and I have no clue what it is. I have tried searching for the markings on the chip, which are as follows:

Top:
HDJ2100-393
937GA1925463B2WW

Bottom:
TAIWAN
937GA1925463B2WW

It is a 40-pin chip.
I found two of these inside of an old CD mixer.
It is a Numark CD-MIX 1, and it was on what appeared to be the display system, as there were two near where the LCDs were. All I could find for a manual is the quickstart guide [here](https://www.numark.com/images/product_downloads/cdmix1_quickstart_guide___v4.2.pdf), but I don't have the manual because it was basically in a giant bin of audio equipment.

Could someone tell me what this is or direct me on how to figure it out?

Comment: Did you find this on the beach in a washed up submarine or in a broken hi-fi? The context would be quite important when trying to identify a chip. Hit the [edit] link to add in the details. Did you mean DIP, DIL or DIN? (If DIN, what does it stand for?)

Comment: You got it - old CD mixer. I meant dual in-line, I see it referred to as DIN.

Comment: C'mon, so, what section is it in? Does it look like audio or display or control? Where's the make and model and link to user manual?

Comment: It is a Numark CD-MIX 1, and it was on what appeared to be thedisplay system, as there were two near where the LCD's were. All I could find for a manual is the quickstart guide [here](https://www.numark.com/images/product_downloads/cdmix1_quickstart_guide___v4.2.pdf), but I don't have the manual because it was basically in a giant bin of audio equipment.

Comment: Make it easy for your readers. All that info belongs in the question, not buried down here.

Comment: Ok, edited. I'm new to asking questions on the network (mostly just a reader)

Comment: I'd say your chances are slim and that that's a custom display driver chip for that range of products. Maybe someone will have a clue.

Comment: Alright. This comment tree is getting long anyway.

Comment: What on earth is driving you to ask this question - stuff - old junk - is best left where you found it.

Comment: I was curious. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @TCoder Because normally it's a waste of everyone's time, yours included. Why do you need to know? Are you trying to replace it? Or are you just curious. Or are you wondering if you can re-use it for something? This last one in particular is a huge waste of time because it is the most difficult way to find a solution for a problem that doesn't exist (because if you don't know what it is for then you don't know what you need it for).

Comment: @DKNguyen I have had these for a while and like most other people during this pandemic, I am bored at home, and I thought it would be a good time to try to figure out what the things do.

Comment: You are just better off reading datasheets for other components then and learning about them than hunting down a datasheet for an anonymous component.

Comment: Ok. I have been doing a ton of that and teaching myself more about electrical engineering in general.

Comment: Another thing is that a lot of mystery ICs in mass-produced consumer products are ICs you won't be able to get information for even if you knew exactly where it came from since the part is not marketed to the public. They are often basically custom-ordered or proprietary so all the information is kept in-house.

Comment: Yeah, I get that a lot.

Comment: Couldn't find this part number, but it's possible the 393 suffix refers to 39K or .039uF.  That might make it a resistor or capacitor array, but 40 pins seems like a lot in that case.  However, it's possible that the display has a massively parallel interface which needs to be pulled up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More often than not, such ICs are custom made for a specific purpose. Their datasheets and other such information is usually private, and not publicly available.

I found a device which fits your description (called Inter-m CDC-2050), and which includes this IC. I couldn't find any datasheet for it, though.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/972704/Inter-M-Cdc-2050.html#manual

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful.

Comment: Glad I could be of any help! :)